# Determine if a word can be constructed from list of subsets - follow-up

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, combinatorics

I have reworked my code as suggested from my previous question: [Determine if a word can be constructed from list of subsets](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37860/determine-if-a-word-can-be-constructed-from-list-of-subsets/37894#37894).

Please instruct me on the complexity along with a review feedback, as explained in the comments below.

```
/**
 * Question is better explained by examples:
 * 1. given
 *    i/p subsets  - ["un", "xy", "te", "i", "d"]
 *    and i/p string is : united should result in true.
 *    and i/p string of : union should result in false.
 *  
 * 2. i/p subsets - ["tonyl", "pqr", "pqrbri",] 
 *    and i/p string of : briton should be true.
 *    and i/p string of : japan should result in false.
 * 
 * 
 * Complexity: 
 * O(n * m) 
 * - where n is number of characters in target
 * - where m is number of subsets
 *
 */
public final class StringFromSubSets {

    private StringFromSubSets() {}

    /**
     * If a word ends with start of a target word, then return the common char count.
     * Eg: for caterpillar and larva, the value returned should be 3 since,
     * 'lar' is end of caterpillar which is common with 'lar' of larva.
     * 
     * If there is no intersection then return 0.
     * 
     * @param end       The word, whose end chars should be considered to find intersection
     * @param target        The word, whose start chars should be considered to find intersection.
     * @return          The number of common chars at end of word end and start of word start.
     */
    private static int subsetEndIntersectsWithTargetStart(String end, String target, int i) {
        assert end != null;
        assert target != null;

        int j = 0;
        while (i < end.length()) {
            if (end.charAt(i) != target.charAt(j)) return 0;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        return j;
    }

    private static final int anySubsetEndIntersectsWithTargetStart(List<String> stringSubsets, String target) {
        assert stringSubsets != null;
        assert target != null;

        for (String string : stringSubsets) {
            for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
                if (string.charAt(i) == target.charAt(0)) {
                    int x = subsetEndIntersectsWithTargetStart (string, target, i);
                    if (x > 0) return x;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the number of common characters in target and and subset which are common from start
     * Eg:
     * "winner" and "wine" will result in return value of 3, since, "win" is the intersection from start.
     * 
     * 
     * @param target        : the target string
     * @param subset        : the subset string
     * @return              : the index which indicates the number of char's in common.
     */
    private static int targetStartIntersectsWithSubsetStart(String target, String subset) {
        assert target != null;
        assert subset != null;

        int i = 0;
        while (i < target.length() && i < subset.length()) {
            if (target.charAt(i) != subset.charAt(i)) return ++i;
            ++i;
        }
        return i;
    }

    private static boolean targetStartIntersectsWithAnySubsetStart(List<String> stringSubsets, String target) {
        assert stringSubsets != null;
        assert target != null;

        if (target.length() == 0) return true;

        for (String string : stringSubsets) {
            int x = targetStartIntersectsWithSubsetStart(target, string);
            if (x > 0) {
                target = target.substring(x);
                if (targetStartIntersectsWithAnySubsetStart(stringSubsets, target)) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean targetFromSubSets(List<String> stringSubsets, String target) {
        if (stringSubsets == null) throw new NullPointerException("The input subset should not be null"); 
        if (target == null) throw new NullPointerException("The target cannot be null");
        if (target.length() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The target should not be zero length");

        // any ends with start ?
        int x = anySubsetEndIntersectsWithTargetStart(stringSubsets, target);
        if (x == 0) return false;
        target = target.substring(x);

        return targetStartIntersectsWithAnySubsetStart(stringSubsets, target);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        List<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<String>();
           listOfString.add("sachin");
           listOfString.add("tendulkar");
           listOfString.add("rahul");
           listOfString.add("dravid");
           System.out.println("Expected true, Actual " + targetFromSubSets(listOfString, "int"));
           System.out.println("Expected true, Actual " + targetFromSubSets(listOfString, "idsa"));
           System.out.println("Expected true, Actual " + targetFromSubSets(listOfString, "sachindravid"));
           System.out.println("Expected true, Actual " + targetFromSubSets(listOfString, "drahultendulkars"));

           System.out.println("Expected false, Actual " + targetFromSubSets(listOfString, "sehwag"));
           System.out.println("Expected false, Actual " + targetFromSubSets(listOfString, "ganguly"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you haven't thought this through. According to my interpretation, I would expect `targetFromSubSets(…, "endul")` to be `true`, but it would print `false`.

Comment: @200_success the question (and previous version) could be clearer, but, I believe `endul` should be false... since `end` is not attached to the beginning or end of an input 'subset' (but is in the middle).

Comment: It is not clear whether SubStrings can be used multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

1. After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (code format) in Eclipse the javadoc will be this:

   ```
   /**
    * Question is better explained by examples: 1. given i/p subsets - ["un", "xy",
    * "te", "i", "d"] and i/p string is : united should result in true. and i/p
    * string of : union should result in false.
   ```

   I think Eclipse is right here because usually javadoc is ends up in HTML documentation which ignores whitespaces. Try to format your javadoc that remains readable in HTML too or use non-javadoc comments:

   ```
   /*
    * Question is better explained by examples:
    * 1. given
    *    i/p subsets  - ["un", "xy", "te", "i", "d"]
   ```

   (Note the only one `*` in the first line. Eclipse does not reformat this one.)
2. It's confusing that the method name indicates a `boolean` return value but actually it's an integer.

   ```
   private static final int anySubsetEndIntersectsWithTargetStart(List<String> stringSubsets, String target) {
       ...
   }
   ```

   Inside the method the return variable is called `x` which still does not help. Name both of them to express their purpose.
3. ```
   private static int targetStartIntersectsWithSubsetStart(String target, String subset) {
   ```

   The same issue is here. Actually, the javadoc is quite good:

   ```
   /**
    * Returns the number of common characters in target and and subset which
    * are common from start Eg: "winner" and "wine" will result in return value
    * of 3, since, "win" is the intersection from start.
   ```

   I'd call the method `getCommonStartCharacterCount` or `getCommonPrefixLength`. (The latter is better.) There is a similar method in [Apache Commons Lang `StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getCommonPrefix%28java.lang.String...%29):

   ```
   String getCommonPrefix(String... strs)
   ```

   One thing which does not trun out from the javadoc why the third one returns `4` here:

   ```
   assertEquals(3, targetStartIntersectsWithSubsetStart("asdx", "asd")); // OK
   assertEquals(3, targetStartIntersectsWithSubsetStart("asd", "asdx")); // OK
   assertEquals(4, targetStartIntersectsWithSubsetStart("asdx", "asdY")); // OK
   ```

   Is it intentional? Why?

   (See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries* The author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.)
4. ```
   for (String string: stringSubsets) {
       for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
           if (string.charAt(i) == target.charAt(0)) {
               int x = subsetEndIntersectsWithTargetStart(string, target, i);
               if (x > 0)
                   return x;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   I'd extract out a local variable here for better readability:

   ```
   final char targetFirstChar = target.charAt(0);
   ```
5. ```
   while (i < target.length() && i < subset.length()) {
   ```

   could be

   ```
   while (i < Math.min(target.length(), subset.length())) {
   ```

   I think it's easier to read since it reveals the intent.
6. You could check first that the the subsets contains every required character for the `target`. If not you can fail early without too much effort.
7. I'd go with something like that [`@rolfl` suggested in this former answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37894/7076). Using a higher level `Set` structures would improve readability and maintainability a lot.

Answer (score 3):

### General

This question still does not have a clear definition, despite the assurances at the top. For example should the following return true:

> ```
> targetFromSubSetsX(listOfString, "raviddraviddraviddra")
> ```

This reuses the same word again, and again...

The description does not give a clear indication whether that is valid or not.

The code in the example says it is valid, but, am I to trust the code?

### Your Solution

I considered how I would solve this problem, then looked at your code, and could not find that pattern.

You do have extensive error checking (for nulls, empty, and otherwise broken input). This is good.

**Bug1:** - then I noticed that you have room for just a single matching start pattern... and that made me think there is a bug.... what if the wrong word matches, and there is not another word that can carry-through on the problem

**Bug2:** but, then I found this code:

> ```
> private static int targetStartIntersectsWithSubsetStart(String target, String subset) {
>     assert target != null;
>     assert subset != null;
>
>     int i = 0;
>     while (i < target.length() && i < subset.length()) {
>         if (target.charAt(i) != subset.charAt(i)) return ++i;
>         ++i;
>     }
>     return i;
> }
> ```

And that code is obviously broken, it returns 1 when nothing matches....

For the input `targetStartIntersectsWithSubsetStart("a", "b")` it returns 1... which is not what it is supposed to do.

This second bug works to make the first bug disappear... because now anything matches!

### Alternate Solution

Putting it together I figure the code is broken....

This is how I would solve the problem... a set-up recursive method, and the actual recursion.

The setup method does the work of identifying whether there is a prefix match on any of the words. If there is a match, it recursively matches the subset words with the target until there is just a 'tail' left.

When I wrote it I assumed that a subset word could only be used once, but, then when I compared it to your results, I found that this is not the case. I have commented out the code that enforced the use-once rule on the subsets.....

```
public static boolean targetFromSubSets(List<String> stringSubsets, String target) {
    for (String word : stringSubsets) {
        Set<String> totry = new HashSet<>(stringSubsets);
        //totry.remove(word);
        
        // OK, we have a word, and a remaining set. Let's see what we can match.
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            String subword = word.substring(i);
            if (target.startsWith(subword)) {
                if (matchExactSubSets(totry, target.substring(subword.length()))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    return false;
}


private static boolean matchExactSubSets(Set<String> totry, String substring) {
    if (substring.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    String[] words = totry.toArray(new String[totry.size()]);
    for (String word : words) {
        if (substring.startsWith(word)) {
            //totry.remove(word);
            //try {
                if (matchExactSubSets(totry, substring.substring(word.length()))) {
                    return true;
                }
            //} finally {
                //totry.add(word);
            //}
        } else if (substring.length() < word.length()) {
            if (word.startsWith(substring)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```